# How to set textview selector in listview item?

Tags: android, listview, textview, selector

I want to change textiew color and listview item's background color when i pressed listview item.
i was set drawable selector to listview  and set color selector textview. each selector work fine but not works same time.

for example, 
press listview > listview selector works, textview selector not works
press textview in listview > texview selctor works , listview selector not works

when i use this option android:duplicateParentState="true"
press textview in listview > nothing happend, both listview and textview selecetor not works.

does anyone have another good idea?

Here is my listview layout.

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="64dp"
android:layout_margin="2dp"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:textColor="@color/color_list_selector"
    android:textSize="22dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and my color selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/clr_black"/>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/clr_black"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/clr_blackt"/>
<item android:color="@color/clr_yellow"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {     
> @Override  
>   public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {  
>     TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
>     textView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getSystem().getDrawable(R.drawable.selector));
> }
> });
> ```

Comment: OnItemClickListener is make doing well. I was set onclickListener on converterview in Adapter getview() method. After remove clicklistener and set ItemClicklistener on listview, everyting is working correctly

Answer (score 0):

As an another idea you can dynamically change the `TextView`'s color and `ListView` item's background color, when item is pressed.

In your custom `ListView`

```
layoutRow.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    switch (event.getAction())
                    {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        // Change the TextView color
                        // Change the ListView item's background color

                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                        // Reset the TextView color                                           
                    // Reset the ListView item's background color

                        return true;

                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Where `layoutRow` is your `ListView` item's layout.In your case you have used `FrameLayout`.

Comment: thanks, but i can't using touch event. should using only onclickEvent cause by BlueTooth keyboad enter event.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly.

Try this color state list for textColor

```html
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#fff"/>
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="#fff"/>
    <item android:color="#000" />
</selector>
```

[Android guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) does not mention `state_activated` attribute but it works for me.